# Would I have ...?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning, modal-verbs

Suppose I flunked math. Right? In this context, I know and understand the meanings of

> Should I have read the text book?

(It was the right thing to do but I didn't) and

> Could I have read the text book?

But what about the meaning of this question?

> Would I have read the text book?

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

The three words have widely different meanings.

"Should" is related to correctness, especially in cases of moral behavior.  "I should brush my teeth before bed." implies that tooth brushing is the right thing to do.

"Could" is related to having the ability or opportunity to do something.  "Could I brush my teeth before bed?" implies that you may not have time to do so, or need permission from someone else.  "Could you take out the trash?" is asking someone for a favor, if they are able to do so.

"Would" is related to an unknown outcome or decision.  "Would brushing my teeth with your toothbrush be gross?" is asking about someone else's reaction.  "Would I study for my math test if I stayed home, or would I just watch TV instead?"  This usage implies another question, which should be clear through context.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that I should've studied for math, but I don't like math at all. I don't think that, even if I considered failing in the exam, I could get myself to study. So that makes me wonder if **I would've even read the textbook**.

In other words, you're questioning your inclination to attempt to read the textbook.